# Is there any relation between Kernel in Set Theory and Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations

I am studying functional analysis and I have never studied set theory. There is that proposition:
Let $E$ be a TVS, $f$ a linear functional over $E$. If the $kerf$ is a closed set, then $f$ is continuous.
My professor used the quotient space $E/Kerf$ and it's canonical map, treating $kerf$ as a relation of equivalence. I googled it and I found that definition in the link (Wikipedia): (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory))
My question is: what is the the relationship between the kernel in linear algebra and the one in set theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(set_theory)#In_algebraic_structures

Comment: It's not the same thing at least from a categorical point of view. You can define a kernel in any category with an initial object $I$ as a pullback (if it exists) along $f:X\to Y$ of the initial morphism $I\to Y$. However, for the category of sets, the initial object $I=\varnothing$ exists as well as pullbacks, which are substes of the cartesian product of the domains of the two maps consisting of those pairs mapped to the same element, which in this case is empty.

Comment: The straightforward relationship is that the set-theoretic kernel is the equivalence relation given by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$, which is equivalent to $x-y$ being contained in the algebraic kernel. You can generalize the set-theoretic kernel and its quotient to general categories (which admit enough limits) and then specialize to abelian categories, where this has a more direct description in terms of kernels and cokernels (equalizers and coequalizers with zero morphisms), which generalizes the above relationship, but I'm not sure if you care about those generalities.